# How to Initialize UIViews and UIViewControllers Using Protocols in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift4, swift-protocols

I've been experimenting lately with building iOS views using a trick I learned from [René Cacheaux](https://twitter.com/rcachATX) to easily initialize UIViewControllers from code:

```swift
class NiblessViewController: UIViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    @available(*, unavailable, message: "Loading this view controller from a nib is unsupported.")
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    @available(*, unavailable, message: "Loading this view controller from a nib is unsupported.")
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Loading this view controller from a nib is unsupported")
    }
}
```

You can then inherit from `NiblessViewController` in your custom view controller classes without having do the initializer overriding each time:

```swift
class CustomViewController: NiblessViewController {
    // ...
}
```

This works great when working with a vanilla `UIViewController`, but I can't figure out a nice way to use it with other view controller classes (e.g. `UITableViewController`, `UINavigationController`) without creating a separate `Nibless` class for each view controller type (e.g. `NiblessTableViewController`, `NiblessNavigationController`), containing the exact same code.

One thing I tried was to use a protocol extension like so:

```swift
protocol Nibless {}

extension Nibless where Self: UIViewController {
    // Same initialization code as above
}
```

Doing it this way, I get three errors saying:

> 1. 'super' cannot be used outside of class members
> 2. 'required' initializer in non-class type 'NiblessViewController'
> 3. initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass

Any ideas on a nice way to do this without having duplicate code?

Comment: Try adding `: class` to your protocol declaration. i.e.`protocol Nibless: class {}`

Comment: @Paolo Darn, that didn't work 

Answer (score 3):

I totally get *why* you are going after what you are (to forbid IB), but it's not possible at the moment. It's also not super practical either. Let me explain:

- The `init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)` method is the class's designated initializer. You should use this whenever initializing a `UIViewController` and marking it unavailable isn't the proper behavior.
- For other subclasses of `UIViewController` they each have their own initializers (like `UITableViewController(style:)`), which wouldn't be covered in your protocol.
- You can mark methods as unavailable in protocols but only `@objc` protocols, and in my brief testing with a playground didn't work like I was hoping it would (that would be very cool if we could do it though).
- However even if we were able to mark protocol items as unavailable, I don't believe we could forbid access to existing members on a class through that technique.

I think your best bet might be to make your own "base" subclasses of each `UIViewController` subclass that you want and expressly forbid IB there. One of the nice things about initialization in code is that you can get rid of `Optional<T>` properties that have to litter IB-bound view controllers.

[Here's a gist that I created which has the base `UIViewController` subclass.](https://gist.github.com/jsorge/f9499795cb82bbffe06e17fad276c274)